# Additional needed documents for UK trip if someone will shoulder all expenses

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

Someone (a relative) from the UK (already a naturalized British Citizen) will be financing my trip, as well as taking care of my accommodation. What are the documents I need to submit aside from bank statements? Does the sponsor need to fill-out the Sponsorship Undertaking Form? (https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/261405/sponsorship-form.pdf)

something to consider from my question:
-my relative is a naturalized citizen in the UK. Is proof of naturalization needed?

Comment: What visa are you applying for? Just the standard visitor visa?

Comment: Hi @nkjt. Yes, just the standard visitor visa.

Answer (score 3):

> What are the documents I need to submit aside from bank statements?

Aside from photos and your passport, there is no 'set' list of documents; each applicant decides what to include.  To do that, you need to examine the [Supporting Documents Guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf) and determine which documents will reveal your personal circumstances most favourably.  Your bank statements will be important despite being co-sponsored because they will show ties to your home country.

You can also benefit by reading [the rules](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) and deciding which documents improve your chances of qualifying.  Pay close attention to V 4.2.

> Does the sponsor need to fill-out the Sponsorship Undertaking Form?

No. The form you linked to is out-of-date anyway and the rules about sponsorship have changed since that form was created. So the only thing you can accomplish with that form is confirm to them that you did not study the guidance (that's a bad thing).

> my relative is a naturalized citizen in the UK. Is proof of
>   naturalization needed?

No. Being a citizen is not a requirement for sponsoring someone and proof of your relative's immigration status is not needed. However it's 'best practices' for sponsors to provide a photocopy of the portrait page of their passport.

They will be much more interested in the your relative's motivation for sponsoring you than they will in their immigration status. They will also be interested in their sponsorship history.

You didn't ask what the sponsor should include in order to establish their capacity for sponsorship, but briefly they should also adhere to the Supporting Documents Guide, including the landlord's permission if the sponsor is not a home owner.

Comment: thank you for this! In your link "V 4.3-V 4.4", as well as in Sec.2 of the supporting documents guide, it wasn't specified what documents will serve as proof for sponsorship of the accommodation. My relative is the home owner. Is any document regarding accommodation needed if this is the case?

Comment: Yes absolutely proof is needed, at least that's how a solicitor would put it. But you are raising a different question in comments. The site is strictly q&a rather than a forum, so for you it's a matter of using 'ask question' once again. It's how this site works, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers